# Altering a server file through javascript code

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a setup of a tablet connected to a Raspberry Pi computer. I want to be able to have a webpage hosted on the Pi change the contents of a file also hosted on the Pi (which will be used in a python script that i have written). I tried having the file inside a hidden iframe, but while my javascript ran, it didn't ever actually change the contents.

How can i set up communication between the webpage and the server files? I know nothing about jQuery in the slightest, but if i have to use it, I will.

Comment: You could use a NodeJS server and communicate via websockets. This would give you bidirectional communication between the web page and the server. I'm not sure what you mean by 'change the server files' as this is pretty nebulous (everything in Unix is a file, for example), but NodeJS certainly has the power to communicate with databases and alter files. As per @Quentins comment you can also use good ol' HTTPcalls if you don't need bidirectional comms

Comment: You need a server side program to make the changes, and either a form or Ajax to send the data to it. It's too broad a topic to provide a complete answer to on Stackoverflow.

Comment: An example implementation would be a simple HTTP form that posts a file to the server. The server then stores that file on disk and runs a git commit for versioning. This is similar to how gists function and gives you version control of your file changes.

Answer (score 0):

While you can actually do something with files in HTML5, you must know that Javascript is a client-side script. In other words JS 'runs' on the persons browser and not really your server.
Languages like PHP actually run on your server, and therefor are able to achieve what you want. 
I'm not THE Javascript expert, and you might even be able to modify a server file with JS but it will be 'hacky' and have a poor implementation and you might need to run a sort of API on your server that actually does the changing..

Save yourself the trouble of doing it like that and pick the right language for the job. I would suggest PHP. Its fairly easy to set that up and run the website. PHP has enough ways to create, view and modify files on the server itself: http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Comment: "you must know that Javascript is a client-side script" your knowledge of javascript is approximately 6 years out of date ;-) https://nodejs.org/ Although, yes, if you run your JavaScript code in the browser it will likely be unable to affect the server outside of HTTP calls and/or websockets. OP's problem seems like an XY problem

Comment: @Dan - Longer than that, Netscape and Microsoft were offering server side JS implementations in the 90s.

Comment: @Quentin While true, it is only since the advent of NodeJS that the server-side javascript ecology has *really* taken off, so I wouldn't blame anyone for not knowing about it until NodeJS

Comment: My knowledge is not out of date, you are trying to compare something while you should not do that. OP is talking about JS itself, you are talking about nodejs which is: Node.js is an open source, cross-platform runtime environment. A nodejs application is written in JS yes, but simply calling nodejs == javascript is very wrong.